# Regex to get from one indent/tab to the next indent/tab in Python

Tags: python, regex, text, docx

The following code works, specifically the regex, to get from one indent/tab to the next instance of a semicolon (;):

```
def find_matches(text):
    return capitalize(
        [
            m
            for m in re.findall(
                r"^[^0-9]\s+([^.;]+\s*)+[.;]+", normalize("NFKD", text), re.MULTILINE
            )
        ]
    )
```

With this, I'm able to produce the following image with the rest of my code:

[image]

My issue lies with my regex pattern, however, as I'm actually moreso supposed to get from the first indent/tab to the next instance of an indent/tab, or I suppose until the next line that is not indented. Here is the raw source string, which is taken from a word document using docx:

[Here is a link to a MediaUpload file of my docx.](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ad8kfivzd94hzxz/P.docx/file) I've chosen to link it since I can't quite get the actual formatting to show correctly on here. Additionally, the second text box is supposed to go a bit longer for an entire line.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
^[^\S\r\n].+(?:\n(?!\s).*)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\r\n]` Match a whitespace char without a newline (indent)
- `.+` Match 1+ times any char except a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\s).*` Negative lookahead, assert not a whitespace char and match the rest of the line
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bg8lE0/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KZfoyK)

---

If the matches have to be part of starting with 1 or more digits followed by a `.` you can first get those matches, and then after process those matches using the first pattern.

```
^\d+\..*(?:\n(?!\d+\.).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xAZxye/1)